# GoogleMapApi3 - hide labels on the fly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

i am using a styled map - now i like to apply a button to hide/show the labels for streets

etc... but when i set a style via "map.setOptions({styles: MyStylesArrayShowLabel});"
that kills all my markers that have a already been placed....

...is there a way to set the style on the fly without destroying the markers?

(all markers [excluded the home marker/infowindo] are generated from a db via sql and php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you have to make use of the `MapTypeIds` and associate a styled map to the ID. Then change your map style on the fly using `map.setMapTypeId([MapTypeId])` as opposed to `map.setOptions([options])`. I would suggest a quick read through the [Styled Maps doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) for reference. But essentially what you have to take note of is 3 things:

1. Create a new StyledMapType object
2. Associate the styled map with a MapTypeId
3. Set the MapType to the display

I have included an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/tLd88/) with comments to the 3 key components you should take note of.

Creating the new StyledMapType is pretty straight forward, so I'll start by explaining the association of the StyledMapType to a MapTypeID:

```
map.mapTypes.set('hide_street_names', hideLabels);
```

Essentially this means you can reference to your `hideLabels` styledmap with a mapTypeID, which in this case is `hide_street_names` - much like you would with `google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` or `google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN` etc.

Then simply trigger your style by switching the MapTypeId on a click action (or however you currently control it), by setting the MapTypeId of your map:

```
map.setMapTypeId('hide_street_names');
```

You'll notice that I revert back to the default view by changing the mapTypeID back to ROADMAP with - `map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);`